# Remove unwanted gaps between images

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, formatting

**The Problem:**

I am trying to display 9 images (that vary in size) in a 3 x 3 grid where each image is displayed neatly next to each other. like in this **[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MTdT.png).** HTML should remain unchanged.

> I don't understand how to fix the uneven gaps between the images
>   displayed. My **[Current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WcP2.png)**

**What I tried:**

My attempt has 3 rows, where each row is contained within a `<div>` tag. Within each row, there are three images displayed.

In the code below I have included the code to show what I did to display the first image within the first row.

I wrapped each image in a HTML `<label>` tag and used Bootstrap and CSS to style the images. My attempt can be found on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dom_sniezka/78dy3to2/

*I am a beginner and I spent the whole day trying to fix this issue but I really don't understand what I am doing wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated.*

---

**html** (For image 1 in row 1...remainder of the code can be found in the JSFiddle link)

```
<div class="container-fluid my-container">
    <form action="addition" method="post">
        <!--First Row, First Image-->
        <div class="row no-pad display-flex">
            <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col- my-col my-col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4 my-col">
                <label for="">
                    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/red-apple-on-white-background-260nw-158989157.jpg">
                    <input type="radio" id="" name="checked-radio" value="normal">
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**css**

```
/* HIDE RADIO */
[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* IMAGE STYLES */
[type=radio] + img {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* CHECKED STYLES */
[type=radio]:checked + img {
  outline: 2px solid #f00;
}


.my-container{
    /*border: 1px solid green;*/
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.img-thumbnail{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

/*Removes gutter in between columns*/
.row.no-pad {
  margin-right:0;
  margin-left:0;
}
.row.no-pad > [class*='col-'] {
  padding-right:0;
  padding-left:0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this css:

```
.img-thumbnail{
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. That worked. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.row.no-pad > [class*='col-'] {
  padding-right:0;
  padding-left:0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display:grid;
}
```

Comment: When you reduce the browser size, it works perfect.